# redirection from HTTP to HTTPS show public folder

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I want to make redirection from http to https.

I try to use this .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

but that show the public folder in the url,

more explain my site is `www.example.com` white this code is going like this `www.example.com/public/`

I have this code is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

and I want to make the redirection to a specific domain, if the users try for example  : `example.com`, I need to redirect to `www.example.com`

any solution ?

Comment: Your problem is still unclear for me..

Comment: @Philipp, first thanks for your time, my problem is when I try to make redirection to HTTPS, the `public` folder shows in the url like this `www.example.com/public/`, I need to avoid it

Comment: To be clear - if you go to `http://www.example.com/` the .htacces currently redirects you to `http://www.example.com/public`?

Comment: @Philipp yep when I add to code of redirection, if I try for example this url `http://www.example.com/` the .htacces currently redirects you to  `https://www.example.com/public/`

Comment: And whats happens, if you remove the code and go directly to `https://www.example.com`?

Comment: nothing, it's be `https://www.example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because you're also requesting the URI in the `RewriteRule`. You need to change the rules to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You can see this rule working [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=5c027ca2-4a4f-5396-a83a-ac765909a76b) with the `/public/` URI and it going to `https://example.com` only. Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this.

Comment: It's work sir, but when I make other page, for example `example.com/test` it's going like this `https://example.com/?test` can I drop the `?` ?

Comment: I think that issue will be caused by your other rules. Place these new rules above those so that they run first.

Comment: if I make it under the rules, give me the error of `?`, and if I make it above the rules, and I try `example.com/test` redirect me to `https://example.com`

Comment: Yes, that is what the above rule does. So it is working... ?

Comment: No, it's redirect me always to the first page

Comment: Your question is very misleading! Then you need to re-add `%{REQUEST_URI}` to the RewriteRule.

Comment: I fix the error sir, I have two .htaccess file, one under public folder, I make it on the other

Comment: but now, I need to redirect if user make `example.com` I need to add `www` like this `www.example.com`

Comment: See my edit, I've added an extra condition that also checks for `www`. It then forces the use of it.